# Performance Issue on Inserting Data using Elastic Search Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

We are using Elastic Search Nest client for our application , we did load testing testing on inserting documents into Elastic Search DB and we found that there is a performance issue.

Index Size 2Kb , Shard Count 5, replica 1, Single Instance DB(no cluster)

Final Results stats tat we could able to insert only 3 records per Second .. is this expected result?

when we increase client threads , results become 2 records per Second , kindly suggest

Test Case

5 parallel thread , each thread synchronously pushing records(10000) .it took around 50 minutes(each thread), 3 record per second insert.

I have created N (5 for this test case) number of Clients on the application startup and reusing it for all the requests.

Server Details : 
16GB RAM , 64 bit OS, Intel Core i7 , Windows Server 2008 R2 , 500 GB hard disk

Client Machine:
16GB RAM , 64 bit OS, Intel Core i7, Windows 7 professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have good performance if you are not using the bulk API.
From 5.0, we `fsync` every single request on the disk.

A Bulk request which can contain for example 10 000 index requests will be `fsync` once.
10 000 index requests will generate 10 000 fsync operations.

For example, on my dataset, switching from 2.x to 5.x I observed the following results:

- **Single index operation:**

  - 2.x: 200 docs/s
  - 5.0: 20 docs/s
- **Bulk operation:**

  - 2.x: 12000-15000 docs/s
  - 5.0: 12000-16000 docs/s

You can if you wish change `index.translog.durability` index setting to `async` but you are taking the risk of dataloss if something goes wrong.

Read more about [Translog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/index-modules-translog.html#_translog_settings_2)